# H.265(libx265) codec for 8K videos, using same compress settings, why yuv444 10-bit is saving bitrates than yuv420 8-bit?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

Our workflow involves huge 8K clips(i.e., 8192x8192). The inputs are mostly very high bitrates 264/265 clips, though we are using ProRes or  DNxHD for post-production within the process, we do not want to archive such huge files as the "master" copies(easily over 100GB for 1 minute).

My current approach is, using FFMPEG to compress the ProRes/DHxHD clips into H.265 clips using a very high-quality setting (crf=12, slow profile).

Another quality related setting is the pixel format config. Then my question comes up:

Targeting the same clips(5 of them), using the same compress settings, one with yuv420 8-bit, one with yuv444 10-bit, yuv444 outputs are constantly smaller than yuv420 outputs(5%-10%), i.e, lower bitrates.

If yuv444 10-bit needs to store more information, how could this be possible?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but may I ask which camers you are using? As not even RED's r3d codec at 8k uses so much storage. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is not from a single camera, they are VR content, a multiple camera setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Why does 10-bit save bandwidth (even when content is 8-bit)?](http://x264.nl/x264/10bit_02-ateme-why_does_10bit_save_bandwidth.pdf)

> When encoding with the 10-bit tool, the compression process is
>   performed with at least 10-bit accuracy compared to only 8-bit
>   otherwise. So there is less truncation errors, especially in the
>   motion compensation  stage, increasing the efficiency of compression 
>   tools. As a consequence, there is less need to quantize to achieve a
>   given bit-rate.
>
> The net result is a better quality for the same bit-rate or conversely
>   less bit-rate for the same quality: between 5% and 20% on typical
>   sources.

See the link for additional info.